# Infinite blog loop

Tags: loop

I can't figure out why I'm getting an infinite blog post. When I comment out loop code in content.php, it no longer loops. I'm trying to post items based on post format and failing so far. Let me know if I need to provide anymore info! I appreciate it.

content.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content. Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @subpackage FoundationPress
 * @since FoundationPress 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php FoundationPress_entry_meta(); ?>
    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(__('Continue reading...', 'FoundationPress')); ?>
    </div>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action('foundationPress_before_content'); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php do_action('foundationPress_before_pagination'); ?>
    <?php endif;?>

    <footer>
        <?php $tag = get_the_tags(); if (!$tag) { } else { ?><p><?php the_tags(); ?></p><?php } ?>
    </footer>
    <hr />
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is named `content.php`, and this line:

```
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
```

will load the same file for posts with standard post format, causing your down-the-rabbit-hole loop.

Comment: I'm trying have it call content-gallery.php or content-quote.php. Do I still take that loop out of content.php? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: the issue is that `get_post_format()` is empty for posts that are standard format, so you're loading `content.php` inside `content.php`, which then loads `content.php`, etc., in an infinite loop. you should rename the above `content.php` to something else if you want to use this structure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Going to dive deeper into it.